# Create server control.Creation issue

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I create a new server control. See the code below:

```
 public class Tree : Control
    {
        #region Rendering
        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
        {
            RenderInputTag(output);
        }

        private void RenderInputTag(HtmlTextWriter htw)
        {
            //Javascript
            htw.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type, "text/javascript");
            htw.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Script);
            htw.Write("<%@ Register Src=\"~/Controls/TreeJavascript.ascx\" TagName=\"Tree\" TagPrefix=\"flt\"%>");
            htw.RenderEndTag();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

But I get the following error, when I want to use the controller:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

how to fix it?

This is the rendered HTML:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
    <%@ Register Src=\"~/Controls/TreeJavascript.ascx\" TagName=\"Tree\" TagPrefix=\"flt\"%>
</script>
```

Comment: You are trying to render server side tags inside HTML, that isn't going to work for sure.

Comment: On what line do you get the error? What is the resulting HTML?

Comment: I got error on this line.I do not have the resulting markup

Comment: What 'this line'? There are 20 lines of code...

Comment: This  error occurs in the browser console, when I want to use server control(htw.Write())

Comment: So, what is the code in the HTML then?

Comment: <script type=text/javascript>
<%@ Register Src=\"~/Controls/TreeJavascript.ascx\" TagName=\"Tree\" TagPrefix=\"flt\"%>
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Since you say the output is this:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
    <%@ Register Src=\"~/Controls/TreeJavascript.ascx\" TagName=\"Tree\" TagPrefix=\"flt\"%>
</script>
```

It is pretty clear the cause of the issue is that the server side tag isn't rendered into code in the HTML. Since `<%` isn't valid in javascript, it breaks.

I think you should initialize the control in code, and call `RenderControl` on it:

```
TreeJavascript t = new TreeJavascript();
t.RenderControl(htw);
```

Else, if the content is just static, save the javascript in a variable and put it in here.

Comment: You should be able to see the namespace in the `TreeJavascript.ascx` or `TreeJavascript.ascx.cs` file. If it hasn't one, you can add it.

Comment: @Denis1: Did you fix it? If so, please accept my answer if it was useful to you.